# How to import text file in vb.net and insert into SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, file, text, import

I'm trying to import a text file into an SQL server. I need to read data inside the file when I upload it and send all the data to an SQL server. Of course inside the SQL I have primary keys where it's going to increment when a new line of data is finished.

HELP!

Comment: I'm still new to VB but I have read about StreamReader, I know how to do the connection between VB and SQL server. @DIe that's it

Comment: As you say, you should be able to put the retrieved 'fileText' into a variable (using StreamReader). You also now how to access SQL server from within your VB application. You just need to create an INSERT statement over your SQLServer database, adding 'fileText' as a parameter... there is no more to it :) plenty of examples around

Comment: Can you help me with the code structure? @DIe

Comment: What have you tried so far? A simple google search "read text and insert sql vb.net" will get you started.

Comment: @obl I created an OpenDialogFile to get the path of the file, so now I need to get the path, read the file and import it to SQL server when I click save button.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question.  I did this a looonnngggg time ago.  See the code below, for a solution to your question.

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim tblReadCSV As New DataTable()

```
tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("FName")
tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("LName")
tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Department")

Dim csvParser As New TextFieldParser("C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Employee.txt")

csvParser.Delimiters = New String() {","}
csvParser.TrimWhiteSpace = True
csvParser.ReadLine()

While Not (csvParser.EndOfData = True)
    tblReadCSV.Rows.Add(csvParser.ReadFields())
End While

Dim con As New SqlConnection("Server=Excel-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;")
Dim strSql As String = "Insert into Employee(FName,LName,Department) values(@Fname,@Lname,@Department)"
'Dim con As New SqlConnection(strCon)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.CommandText = strSql
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "FName")
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Lname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "LName")
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Department", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Department")

Dim dAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
dAdapter.InsertCommand = cmd
Dim result As Integer = dAdapter.Update(tblReadCSV)
```

End Sub

Also, see ALL the code below, for several similar, and related, tasks.  Notice, I added a few comments, but not too many...

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Configuration


Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        Dim headers = (From header As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn)() Select header.HeaderText).ToArray
        Dim rows = From row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() Where Not row.IsNewRow Select Array.ConvertAll(row.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).ToArray, Function(c) If(c.Value IsNot Nothing, c.Value.ToString, ""))
        Dim str As String = ""
        Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\OrdersTest.csv")
            sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", headers))
            'sw.WriteLine(String.Join(","))
            For Each r In rows
                sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", r))
            Next
            sw.Close()
        End Using

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'Dim m_strConnection As String = "server=Excel-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;"

        'Catch ex As Exception
        '    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        'End Try

        'Dim objDataset1 As DataSet()
        'Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Dim da As OdbcDataAdapter
        Dim OpenFile As New System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog ' Does something w/ the OpenFileDialog
        Dim strFullPath As String, strFileName As String
        Dim tbFile As New TextBox
        ' Sets some OpenFileDialog box options
        OpenFile.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*" ' Shows only .csv files
        OpenFile.Title = "Browse to file:" ' Title at the top of the dialog box

        If OpenFile.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then ' Makes the open file dialog box show up
            strFullPath = OpenFile.FileName ' Assigns variable
            strFileName = Path.GetFileName(strFullPath)

            If OpenFile.FileNames.Length > 0 Then ' Checks to see if they've picked a file

                tbFile.Text = strFullPath ' Puts the filename in the textbox

                ' The connection string for reading into data connection form
                Dim connStr As String
                connStr = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)}; Dbq=" + Path.GetDirectoryName(strFullPath) + "; Extensions=csv,txt "

                ' Sets up the data set and gets stuff from .csv file
                Dim Conn As New OdbcConnection(connStr)
                Dim ds As DataSet
                Dim DataAdapter As New OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + strFileName + "]", Conn)
                ds = New DataSet

                Try
                    DataAdapter.Fill(ds, strFileName) ' Fills data grid..
                    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(strFileName) ' ..according to data source

                    ' Catch and display database errors
                Catch ex As OdbcException
                    Dim odbcError As OdbcError
                    For Each odbcError In ex.Errors
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                    Next
                End Try

                ' Cleanup
                OpenFile.Dispose()
                Conn.Dispose()
                DataAdapter.Dispose()
                ds.Dispose()

            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim cnn As SqlConnection
        Dim connectionString As String
        Dim sql As String

        connectionString = "data source=Excel-PC\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
        "initial catalog=NORTHWIND;Trusted_Connection=True"
        cnn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        cnn.Open()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM [Order Details]"
        Dim dscmd As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        dscmd.Fill(ds)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

        cnn.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ProductsDataGridView_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object,
                                                ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) _
                                                Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting

        If e.ColumnIndex = DataGridView1.Columns(3).Index _
            AndAlso e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
            '
            If CInt(e.Value) < 10 Then
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow
            End If
            '
        End If
        '
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Dim tblReadCSV As New DataTable()

        tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("FName")
        tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("LName")
        tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Department")

        Dim csvParser As New TextFieldParser("C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Employee.txt")

        csvParser.Delimiters = New String() {","}
        csvParser.TrimWhiteSpace = True
        csvParser.ReadLine()

        While Not (csvParser.EndOfData = True)
            tblReadCSV.Rows.Add(csvParser.ReadFields())
        End While

        Dim con As New SqlConnection("Server=Excel-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;")
        Dim strSql As String = "Insert into Employee(FName,LName,Department) values(@Fname,@Lname,@Department)"
        'Dim con As New SqlConnection(strCon)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = strSql
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "FName")
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Lname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "LName")
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Department", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Department")

        Dim dAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
        dAdapter.InsertCommand = cmd
        Dim result As Integer = dAdapter.Update(tblReadCSV)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

        Dim SQLConnectionString As String = "Data Source=Excel-PC\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
                            "Initial Catalog=Northwind;" & _
                            "Trusted_Connection=True"

        ' Open a connection to the AdventureWorks database.
        Using SourceConnection As SqlConnection = _
           New SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString)
            SourceConnection.Open()

            ' Perform an initial count on the destination table.
            Dim CommandRowCount As New SqlCommand( _
            "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Orders;", _
                SourceConnection)
            Dim CountStart As Long = _
               System.Convert.ToInt32(CommandRowCount.ExecuteScalar())
            Console.WriteLine("Starting row count = {0}", CountStart)

            ' Get data from the source table as a AccessDataReader.
            'Dim ConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
            '    "Data Source=" & "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\OrdersTest.txt" & ";" & _
            '    "Extended Properties=" & "text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"","";"

            Dim ConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\" & ";" & _
                "Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=No"""

            Dim TextConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)

            Dim TextCommand As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM OrdersTest#csv", TextConnection)
            TextConnection.Open()
            Dim TextDataReader As OleDbDataReader = TextCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)

            ' Open the destination connection.              
            Using DestinationConnection As SqlConnection = _
                New SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString)
                DestinationConnection.Open()

                ' Set up the bulk copy object. 
                ' The column positions in the source data reader 
                ' match the column positions in the destination table, 
                ' so there is no need to map columns.
                Using BulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = _
                  New SqlBulkCopy(DestinationConnection)
                    BulkCopy.DestinationTableName = _
                    "dbo.Orders"

                    Try
                        ' Write from the source to the destination.
                        BulkCopy.WriteToServer(TextDataReader)

                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)

                    Finally
                        ' Close the AccessDataReader. The SqlBulkCopy
                        ' object is automatically closed at the end
                        ' of the Using block.
                        TextDataReader.Close()
                    End Try
                End Using

                ' Perform a final count on the destination table
                ' to see how many rows were added.
                Dim CountEnd As Long = _
                    System.Convert.ToInt32(CommandRowCount.ExecuteScalar())
                'Console.WriteLine("Ending row count = {0}", CountEnd)
                'Console.WriteLine("{0} rows were added.", CountEnd - CountStart)
            End Using
        End Using


        'Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\OrdersTest.csv"
        'Dim TextLine As String

        'If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
        '    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
        '    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
        '        TextLine = TextLine & objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine
        '    Loop
        'Else
        '    MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
        'End If

        'Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=Excel-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;")
        'Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

        'cmd.Connection = cn

        'cmd.Connection.Close()
        'cmd.Connection.Open()

        'cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Orders (OrderID,CustomerID,EmployeeID,OrderDate,RequiredDate,ShippedDate,ShipVia,Freight,ShipName,ShipAddress,ShipCity,ShipRegion,ShipPostalCode,ShipCountry) values & OrdersTest.csv"
        'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'cmd.Connection.Close()

    End Sub


Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        ' Define the Column Definition                             
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.Add("OrderID", GetType(Integer))
        dt.Columns.Add("CustomerID", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("EmployeeID", GetType(Integer))
        dt.Columns.Add("OrderDate", GetType(Date))
        dt.Columns.Add("RequiredDate", GetType(Date))
        dt.Columns.Add("ShippedDate", GetType(Date))
        dt.Columns.Add("ShipVia", GetType(Integer))
        dt.Columns.Add("Freight", GetType(Decimal))
        dt.Columns.Add("ShipName", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("ShipAddress", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("ShipCity", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("ShipRegion", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("ShipPostalCode", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("ShipCountry", GetType(String))
        Using cn = New SqlConnection("Server=Excel-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;")
            cn.Open()
            Dim reader As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser
            Dim currentRow As String()
            Dim dr As DataRow
            Dim sqlColumnDataType As String
            reader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFieldParser("C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\OrdersTest.csv")
            reader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            reader.Delimiters = New String() {","}
            While Not reader.EndOfData
                Try
                    currentRow = reader.ReadFields()
                    dr = dt.NewRow()
                    For currColumn = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                        sqlColumnDataType = dt.Columns(currColumn).DataType.Name
                        Select Case sqlColumnDataType
                            Case "String"
                                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRow(currColumn)) Then
                                    dr.Item(currColumn) = ""
                                Else
                                    dr.Item(currColumn) = Convert.ToString(currentRow(currColumn))
                                End If
                            Case "Decimal"
                                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRow(currColumn)) Then
                                    dr.Item(currColumn) = 0
                                Else
                                    dr.Item(currColumn) = Convert.ToDecimal(currentRow(currColumn))
                                End If
                            Case "DateTime"
                                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRow(currColumn)) Then
                                    dr.Item(currColumn) = ""
                                Else
                                    dr.Item(currColumn) = Convert.ToDateTime(currentRow(currColumn))
                                End If
                        End Select
                    Next
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
                Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                    MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & "is not valid." & vbCrLf & "Terminating Read Operation.")
                    reader.Close()
                    reader.Dispose()
                    'Return False
                Finally
                    dr = Nothing
                End Try
            End While
            Using copy As New SqlBulkCopy(cn)
                copy.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[Orders]"
                copy.WriteToServer(dt)
            End Using
        End Using

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click

        'Dim cnn As SqlConnection
        'Dim connectionString As String
        'Dim sql As String
        'connectionString = "data source=Excel-PC\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
        '"initial catalog=NORTHWIND;Trusted_Connection=True"
        'cnn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        'cnn.Open()
        'GetCsvData("C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\OrdersTest.csv", dbo.Orders)

    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetCsvData(ByVal CSVFileName As String, ByRef CSVTable As DataTable) As Boolean
        Dim reader As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser
        Dim currentRow As String()
        Dim dr As DataRow
        Dim sqlColumnDataType As String
        reader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFieldParser(CSVFileName)
        reader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        reader.Delimiters = New String() {","}
        While Not reader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = reader.ReadFields()
                dr = CSVTable.NewRow()
                For currColumn = 0 To CSVTable.Columns.Count - 1
                    sqlColumnDataType = CSVTable.Columns(currColumn).DataType.Name
                    Select Case sqlColumnDataType
                        Case "String"
                            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRow(currColumn)) Then
                                dr.Item(currColumn) = ""
                            Else
                                dr.Item(currColumn) = Convert.ToString(currentRow(currColumn))
                            End If
                        Case "Decimal"
                            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRow(currColumn)) Then
                                dr.Item(currColumn) = 0
                            Else
                                dr.Item(currColumn) = Convert.ToDecimal(currentRow(currColumn))
                            End If
                        Case "DateTime"
                            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRow(currColumn)) Then
                                dr.Item(currColumn) = ""
                            Else
                                dr.Item(currColumn) = Convert.ToDateTime(currentRow(currColumn))
                            End If
                    End Select
                Next
                CSVTable.Rows.Add(dr)
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & "is not valid." & vbCrLf & "Terminating Read Operation.")
                reader.Close()
                reader.Dispose()
                Return False
            Finally
                dr = Nothing
            End Try
        End While
        reader.Close()
        reader.Dispose()
        Return True
    End Function

    Private Sub DataGridView1_RowValidating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs)


    End Sub

End Class
```

One more to try . . .

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim file As String = "Import.txt"
        Dim path As String = "C:\Users\path_to_text_file\"
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Try
            If IO.File.Exists(IO.Path.Combine(path, file)) Then
                Dim ConStr As String = _
                "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
                path & ";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited\"""
                Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConStr)
                Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from " & _
                file, conn)
                da.Fill(ds, "TextFile")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - an open source ETL framework, you can load the entire file to database with few lines of code as below (the code is in c#, hope you can translate it to vb.net)

```
string connectionstring = 
@"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=TestDb;Integrated Security=True";

using (SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionstring))
{
    using (var dr = new ChoCSVReader<Customer>
    ("Cust.csv").WithFirstLineHeader().AsDataReader())
    {
        bcp.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Customers";
        bcp.EnableStreaming = true;


        bcp.BatchSize = 10000;
        bcp.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
        bcp.NotifyAfter = 10;
        bcp.SqlRowsCopied += delegate (object sender, SqlRowsCopiedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.RowsCopied.ToString("#,##0") + " rows copied.");
        };
        bcp.WriteToServer(dr);
    }
}
```

For more details, visit the [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1170498/Cinchoo-ETL-Bulk-Insert-CSV-File-into-SQLServer) article

Disclosure: I'm the author of this library.